# Enhancements on Weapons/Armor for a Druid

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, optimization

I'm having issues finding possible enchantments for my druid. I'm drafting up a lvl 14 druid, no need to worry about wealth. I just want to know what kind of enchantments would be useful for a wild shaping druid.

So far, I've got a quarterstaff with no enhancements, and I can't really seem to find any useful weapon enhancements that's still in effect in wild shape. Changing the weapon to a different type is also okay. What enhancements are available for the quarterstaff to use when melded? If I go the route of dropping the quarterstaff and picking it up, what enhancements would be useful to make my wild shape more powerful?

As for the armor, I was thinking dragonhide/ironwood full plate with the wild armor enchantment. Add that with a Monk's belt that uses the wildling clasp for some pretty good survivability. That being said, what other types of armor enchantments can I use in wild shape? And if I have wild armor with another enhancement, can I use both enhancements in wild shape?

Forgot to add accessories, but I also was wondering but can items such as Periapt of Wisdom stay useful in wild shape or do I need to get a wildling clasp for that too?

Not looking for perfect optimization, just what kind of useful enchantments there are for a wild shaping druid?

And lastly, I tend to have issues with wording a question, so if it's unsatisfactory please let me know why and I'll do my best to fix it.

Comment: RE: "…I can't really seem to find any useful weapon enhancements that's still in effect in wild shape." I'm not sure what this means. If you're carrying the quarterstaff when you use wild shape, it melds and becomes nonfuctional. If you drop the quarterstaff then use wild shape the pick up the quarterstaff, go ahead, Mr. Bear-druid, and beat on folks with your magic quarterstaff. Or did you want the quarterstaff to *both* meld *and* grant bonuses?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to know if it can meld AND grant bonuses? Similar to what the wild armor enchantment can do.

Comment: @RionMurphy There doesn't seem to be a clear question in your....."question".  Which isn't good here.

Comment: @godskook *Clear* being the operative word. The question is *What magic armor special abilities and magic weapon special abilities are the most useful to a druid in wild shape?* (I think the answer to the weapon one may be *None*, though, so the question should be further narrowed to magic armor and shield special abilities…, but then, after *wild* itself, the question might be too broad.) Rion, so this can be narrowed even more, are you looking for defense, offense, or utility?

Comment: Considering that if I bring this character into the game I'm thinking of, we've got plenty of offense and utility. So let's go with defense with a sprinkling of utility.